# Showing that $\exists f \in X^*$ : $\|f\| = \frac{1}{d(x_0,Y)}, \; f(x_0) = 1$ and $f(y) = 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem, hahn-banach-theorem

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of $X$. If $x_0 \notin Y$, show that there exists $f \in X^*$ such that :
>   $$\|f\| = \frac{1}{d(x_0,Y)}, \; f(x_0) = 1 \; \text{and} \; f(y) = 0$$

**Attempt :**

I know the following Lemma :

> **Lemma :** Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of $X$ with $x_0 \in X \setminus Y$. Then, there exists $f \in S_{X^*}$ such that $f(y) =0$ and $f(x_0) = d(x_0,Y)$.

Using the lemma above for our exercise, I can say that there exists $g \in S_{X^*}$ such that $g(x_0) = d(x_0,Y)$ and $g(y)=0$.

Now, let :

$$f := \frac{1}{d(x_0,Y)}g$$

This means that :

$$f(x_0) = \frac{1}{d(x_0,Y)}g(x_0) = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad f(y) = 0$$

Finally, for the operator norm of $f$ it is $\|g\| = 1$ since $g \in S_{X^*}$, which straightforwardly implies  :

$$\|f\| = \frac{1}{d(x_0,Y)}$$

**Question :** Is my approach correct and rigorous enough ? Other than that easy way out, is there a more standard solution approach ?